# nginx as load balancer not forwarding to ports

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

I am not getting the expected behaviour from my nginx configured as a load balancer.

The load balancer part is working, but I am trying to forward to different ports but it is just going out on the original port 80. Here is my load-balancer.conf

```
        upstream backend {
                server public_ip1:18004;
                server public_ip2:18004;
   }

        server {
                listen 80;

      location / {
          proxy_pass http://backend;
      }
   }
```

If I go to the IP address of the load balancer, it will round robin the two public_ip addresses, but does not forward to the port 18004 specified, instead it forwards to port 80.

I was expecting the behaviour to be:

lb_ip:80 -> public_ip1:18004 (or public_ip2:18004)

If I add `listen 18004;`  in the `server {}` element and go to lb_ip:18004 it does work (goes to port 18004), but I wanted to know why it doesn't listen on port 80 and forward to the port specified in the `server {}` element?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you restarted nginx?

Comment: Yes I have restarted